# WPF Change style using blend

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blend

Is it possible using only xaml to change for example Property in style by blend triggers? For example after firing event `Checked` on first `RadioButton` change property `Visibility` in style `FirstStyle` on `Visible`.

```
<Window x:Class="switch_style.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Interactivity="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:Interactions="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FirstStyle" TargetType="Label" x:Name="block">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Style="{DynamicResource FirstStyle}">First</Label>
                <Label>Second</Label>
                <Label>Third</Label>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical">
                <RadioButton Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="First">
                    <Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <Interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                            <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="{Binding block}"  PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Interactivity:EventTrigger>
                    </Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                </RadioButton>
                <RadioButton Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Second</RadioButton>
                <RadioButton Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Third</RadioButton>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: If you are trying to make Labels visible/invisible depending on whether a RadioButton is checked or not, then why not directly bind Label's visibility to RadioButton IsChecked property?

Comment: @sthotakura, maybe it is good idea. If i should use one style and in them i should bind visibility of label to check property in button. But how to bind Value={Binding ...} in style to the control property?

Comment: Hmm.. that's tricky. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A `Style` object becomes immutable the moment it is applied to a `Control`. If this `Style` is not applied yet, yes you can change it.

So, you should create 2 separate `Styles` and choose a `Style` based on `Trigger`.

Answer (score 1):

Since, I am not too sure why you want to do only in XAML, but here is my attempt and it works.

I updated your style to the following:

```
  <Style x:Key="FirstStyle" TargetType="Label">
     <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
     <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Value="True">
           <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

And then, I set `DataContext` on `Label`s to the corresponding `RadioButton`s. Here is the full XAML:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <Page.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="FirstStyle" TargetType="Label">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Page.Resources>
   <Grid>
      <Grid>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="First" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=radioButton1}" Style="{DynamicResource FirstStyle}"/>
            <Label Content="Second" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=radioButton2}" Style="{DynamicResource FirstStyle}"/>
            <Label Content="Third" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=radioButton3}" Style="{DynamicResource FirstStyle}"/>
         </StackPanel>
         <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical">
            <RadioButton
               x:Name="radioButton1"
               Width="60"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Content="First"/>
            <RadioButton
               x:Name="radioButton2"
               Width="60"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Content="Second"/>
            <RadioButton
               x:Name="radioButton3"
               Width="60"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Content="Third"/>
         </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
   </Grid>
</Page>
```

It would have probably been easier if we could bind `RadioButton`'s `IsChecked` and `Label`s Visibility to the same property on a backing ViewModel.

Another approach to this problem would be @AnjumSKhan's answer.